# jQuery (Nvio slider) not firing on a CodeIgniter app once moved to Media Temple host

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter, mediatemple

I am hoping someone might know the answer to this off the top. I have developed this site on a Fedora box, then moved it to my test box (link below) running Ubuntu Svr 10.10/Apache2/PHP5/MySQL5.1 and all works fine through on the dev and test platforms.

I have researched the Media Temple, Code Igniter (using 1.7) & jQuery forums for the past two days and so far and can't find a similar issue where the script does not fire the function and my js and css paths are correct.

Specifics:

I have run the following code successfully on my development and self hosted test server with results that pass. Once the same code and same database is moved to Media Temple the jQuery stops firing.

The test server link is (so you can see it work): http://ganymede.likescandy.com/site/
On view source you see the pictures in the slider  which give us that nice slider action.

The Media Temple link where it fails is: http://jeffbreece.com/site

The code that is not firing on the Media Temple hosted code is this function (but does on both the test hosts):

```
<!-- script --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/site/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/site/js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('#slider').nivoSlider({
            effect:'sliceUpDown',
            pauseTime:5000,
            directionNav:false
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: btw, you need to preload the images somehow, this effect as it is looks not very nice. Or maybe comprimze the sizes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the jQuery code dose not get loaded as I can see. Chrome throws an error in the minimized version, which is saying that some number made the error, which results in jQuery not get loaded fully. After pageload, jQuery is undefined, so you have a problem with you script, either mallformed minimized or somethin else.

Yeah I found it, the two jQuery files are different. Open both jQuery files, i then scrolled and saw that they differ...

Comment: I saw the same error in the JQuery library file... @Jeff any chance they could have been modified during deployment?

Comment: Thanks guys, I am going to FTP new js files over now and retest.

Comment: @Chris; I re ftp'd fresh jQuery and got the same results. Then just added this link instead and presto it worked.<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>